# How many permutations are there such that partial sums of that permutations are always positive?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am trying assignments and I am unable to think about how to solve this problem.

> Problem is let S be a set such that S =  { n•1 , n• -1} ie set S has n number of +1 and n number of -1 . 
>   How many permutations are there such that partial sums of that permutations are always positive?
>
> I thought if x be number of times +1 is chosen and y be number of times -1 is chosen then x-y must be >0 . So  choices need to satisfy this inequality. But I am unable to find a way as to how to find such choices as -y term is there.

Can someone please help.

Comment: See [Catalan Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).

Comment: Please write a title specific to the question.